# How I combine dll files for c# project?

Tags: c#, dll

I have 4 dll files in my c# project. I want to combine 4 dll files in 1 dll. How can I do it?

Comment: Just paste the title of your question into google and you get the answer.  A minimum amount of research is expected here.

Comment: I did not find more information on google. maybe anybody knows it in here @HansPassant

Comment: @akdrmrk I wanted to give you the benefit of the doubt... so I Googled this myself and got about 10 good answers.  Including ILMerge.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try: [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)? ILMerge is a utility that can be used to merge multiple .NET assemblies into a single assembly.

Comment: thanks bro. Now I will make research about ILMerge @JonnyPiazzi